# Need a return value from a stored procedure in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql, stored-procedures

**With the following Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2005**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[UserProfile]') IS NOT NULL

DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserProfile]  

GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserProfile] 
(      
      @UserId VARCHAR(20)
)

AS

IF @UserId = 'userId'
BEGIN
SELECT @UserId = 'Yes'
END

ELSE
SELECT @UserId = 'No'

  SELECT @UserId AS RESULT 

  RETURN RESULT

GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO
```

**C# code, needs to obtain the result of the stored procedure**

```
public String UserProfile(string userId)
{
   String result;
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand cmd = this.mConn.CreateCommand();

   try
   {

       cmd.CommandTimeout = this.mCmdTimeout;
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       cmd.CommandText = "UserProfile";

       DbParameter p = cmd.CreateParameter();

       p.ParameterName = "@UserId";
       p.DbType = DbType.String;
       p.Value = userId;

       cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

       cmd.Connection.Open();
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       cmd.Connection.Close();

       //Need to assign the value of the stored procedure's return to result
       result = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@UserId"].Value);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       throw;
   }
   finally
   {
       cmd.Connection.Close();
   }

   return result;
}
```

**How do I return the result of my stored procedure in C#?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, you can use the ExecuteScalar() method of Command to return the value. ExecuteScalar will look at the first column of the first record returned from the database.

Comment: simple stuff, that's what I was looking for.  Also you must cast to the type you want, in this case it is a String.

Comment: Yes, this is by far the simplest answer.

Comment: This method doesn't work for a stored procedure with a return value instead of an output value or row(s) returned. See user_v's answer for return values.

Comment: I agree with Josh, this is a solution that will only work for specific queries and is not appropriate as a general solution to OP's question. Using a parameter with Direction = ReturnValue as documented by @user_v is a general solution.

Answer (score 8):

I was also looking for returning value from Stored procedure and capture it in C#.

I was returning various return codes based on the logic in my code, and executescalar will not help as I wanted to return out of stored proc in between wherever required with the appropriate code and not use select.
So by adding an extra parameter with Direction as ReturnValue, you can capture the return value. No need of OUT parameters to capture return value from stored proc.

```
       preturn.ParameterName = "@Return_Value";  
       preturn.DbType = DbType.Int;        
       preturn.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

So here is what I came up with. Editing the original code in this post to keep it simple.

```
public String UserProfile(string userId)  
{  
   String result;  
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand cmd = this.mConn.CreateCommand();  

   try  
   {  

       cmd.CommandTimeout = this.mCmdTimeout;  
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  
       cmd.CommandText = "UserProfile";  

       DbParameter p = cmd.CreateParameter();  

       p.ParameterName = "@UserId";  
       p.DbType = DbType.String;  
       p.Value = userId;  

       cmd.Parameters.Add(p);  

       DbParameter preturn = cmd.CreateParameter();        
       preturn.ParameterName = "@Return_Value";  
       preturn.DbType = DbType.Int;        
       preturn.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

       cmd.Parameters.Add(preturn);  

       cmd.Connection.Open();  
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
       cmd.Connection.Close();  

       //Need to assign the value of the stored procedure's return to result  
       result = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@Return_Value"].Value);  
   }  
   catch (Exception ex)  
   {  
       throw;  
   }  
   finally  
   {  
       cmd.Connection.Close();  
   }  

   return result;  
}
```

Comment: Please note that the parameter name is arbitrary, the key factor is that the direction is ReturnValue. You can only have a single parameter for a command with a direction of ReturnValue. Note too that the parameter name does not match any existing parameter declared for this command.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding this to the parameter's properties before executing the command:

```
cmd.Parameters["@UserId"].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
```

**Edit: **
As Ryan Brunner stated in comments, you must mark your parameter as OUT in the stored procedure for this to work.

Comment: In order for this to work @UserID needs to be marked as an output parameter in the stored proc as well.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right.  @Chris Ballance, heed Ryan's advice if you take this approach!  I will edit.

Comment: +1 for your post and for the community making your post better

Answer (score 3):

You can use an Output parameter as well.

In storedprocedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserProfile] 
(      
      @UserId VARCHAR(20) Output
)
```

In code:

```
p.ParameterName = "@UserId";
p.DbType = DbType.String;
p.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
p.Value = userId;
```

Comment: This would involve altering the stored procedure itself, add a parameter to the command using a direction of System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue is all you need to do capture the Return value from the stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You could have also used an Output parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Using...?

Linq2Entities? Drag the sproc into the designer and it will be a function in c# returning the correct value.
Linq2Sql? Drag the sproc into the designer and it will be a function in c# returning the correct value.
ADO? - just assign the result of ExecuteScalar to a variable

Comment: @Russell, that is what Tags are for, they clearly state he is using SQL C# and its a sproc within SQL.

Comment: JonH - Those are all valid ways to do it IN C# with SQL.